# I can't access the modules page

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

I have installed a few modules for the site; one of them is causing an error, and I can't access the modules page.

The error I see is the following one:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function ctools_include() in
>   /var/www/vhosts/haweraprezchurch.org.nz/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/features/includes/features.ctools.inc on line 226

How can I access the module page?

In my case I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: I cant get into modules it should say in discription

Answer (score 2):

I always find the simplest way to deal with this is just to go to the `system` table in the site's database, and set the `status` column for the problematic module to `0`.

After clearing the cache tables (either with Drush, or manually) you should be able to access the modules page again.

Comment: I'm not so sure about disabling Features here (although it is causing an issue).  He could potentially break..well...some of the features of the site.

This answer is very very correct, but I'd check if Chaos Tools exists/is enabled first just in case :-)

Comment: @Chapabu Yeah you're right, I normally go brute-force on these sorts of things until the bugger lets me back in to my admin section...then I start worrying about repercussions ;) Also (and I'm not entirely sure about this) Drush bootstraps Drupal in order to enable modules...if there's an error in the features module it *might* stop that bootstrap from completing successfully, or even running at all, and installing/enabling ctools might fail altogether. I haven't checked how true that is though

Comment: I think Drush uses different levels of the bootstrap for different things.  [This](http://drush.ws/docs/bootstrap.html) is a good reference I found hidden in the docs.  Anything on the module enabling phase  I guess would only need to bootstrap to level 2 (database)..whereas the code error would be (I guess) apparent at level 7 (full).  This is assuming that modules are enabled directly in the database with Drush, and not using `module_enable`.

Comment: @Chapabu That makes a lot of sense cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your error message means that the Features module is looking for Chaos Tools function that it can't find.

It looks to me like you haven't got Chaos Tools enabled, as the `ctools_include` function does exist in the latest version.

If you use Drush, head to the terminal and type `drush en ctools` to enable Chaos Tools, or `drush dl ctools` to actually GET Chaos Tools if you don't have it and see if the error message persists.

If you don't use Drush, then go and get Drush :-)